# Sending notification email from Javascript/Tampermonkey/Greasemonkey (without Server)

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, email, tampermonkey

I need to send notifications from front-end. Notifications are going to have analytical data from website being monitored with Tampermonkey Chrome extension.

Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe  this one https://formspree.io/ or at least something that follows the same idea.